# How to refactor long if statment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I have a long if statement that I'm wanting to refactor. The statement listens for a click and then updates one of five text boxes depending on if those text boxes have anything in them or not. How could I change my code to be more efficient.

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
if ($('#card1').val().length === 0) {
    $('#card1').val('A feeling of warmth');
} else if ($('#card2').val().length === 0)  {
    $('#card2').val('A feeling of warmth');
} else if ($('#card3').val().length === 0){
  $('#card3').val('A feeling of warmth');
} else if ($('#card4').val().length === 0){
  $('#card4').val('A feeling of warmth');
} else if ($('#card5').val().length === 0){
  $('#card5').val('A feeling of warmth');
}

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use a loop

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
    var items = ["#card1", "#card2", "etc"];
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        if ($(items[i]).val().length === 0) {
            $(items[i]).val('A feeling of warmth');
        }
    }
});
```

it's at least easier to read. Also if your buttons are always card + a number you could make it even simplier (not easier to read, just less lines & maintenance)

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
    for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
        if ($("#card" + i).val().length === 0) {
            $("#card" + i).val('A feeling of warmth');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using JQuery. You can use a selector and a filter to isolate the first empty item:

```js
$('#img1').click(function() {
  $('input:text[id^=card]')
    .filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; })
    .first()
    .val('A feeling of warmth');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="img1">CLICK ME</button><br>
<input id="card1"><br>
<input id="card2"><br>
<input id="card3"><br>
<input id="card4"><br>
<input id="card5">
```

`$('input:text[id^=card]')` selects all text inputs whose IDs begin with 'card'. But the same principle would apply to other element types.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
// num can be total count of the element like $(.card).children.count
var num = 5, // preferably dont make it hardcoded.
    str = 'A feeling of warmth',
    preIdStr = '#card',
    id;
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i += 1) {
    id = preIdStr + i;
    if ($(id).val().length === 0) {
        $(id).val(str);
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Give all cards the same `class`.
Then use the selector `$('.yourclass')`

Now use the jQuery for-each (.each) function to iterate all elements. Within the loop you check the value, set it to whatever you want and return `false` when the value was set, since this exit's the loop.

```
$('.yourclass').each(
    function () {
        if (this.val().length === 0) {
            this.val('your value');
            return false; // exit loop
        }
    });
```